# RecyclerView Item height not changing when child ImageView rotated

Tags: android, imageview, android-recyclerview, objectanimator

I Have a RecyclerView Item with the following layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:padding="@dimen/margin_default"
>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:transitionName="cimage"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    />


<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/flip_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_flip"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_default"/>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/rotate_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_action_rotate"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/image"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_default"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The RecyclerView Item is fine when its first loaded and the ImageView is not rotated
[image: ImageView is perfect, showing the full image correctly]

But when the ImageView is rotated with a ObjectAnimator ImageView gets truncated at top and bottom edges, RelativeLayout constraints are also violated
[image: ImageView getting truncated when rotated]

Here is the code inside ViewHolder that rotates the ImageView on a button click

```
rotateAnimator = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(mImageView, "rotation", 0f, 90f);
    rotateAnimator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator());

    rotateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (rotateAnimator.getAnimatedFraction() == 1) {
                rotateAnimator.reverse();
            } else {
                rotateAnimator.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

I have tried invalidating the ImageView when the animation ends but that didn't work. I have also tried wrapping the ImageView inside a FrameLayout container and then invalidating the FrameLayout when animation ends but with no luck.

Comment: Maybe some scaling attribute can help you, like `android:scaleType="centerInside"` (can't remember the exact name right now).

Answer (score 0):

I have somewhat solved the issue. I have wrapped the ImageView in a FrameLayout and then set the Height of that FrameLayout in the animation listener. Here's the code:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/img_lt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/credential_image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:transitionName="credential_image"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

The animation listener:

```
rotateAnimator.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
        int width, height;
        @Override
        public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {
            width = mImageView.getMeasuredWidth();
            height = mImageView.getMeasuredHeight();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
            ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = mParent.getLayoutParams();

           if(rotateAnimator.getAnimatedFraction() == 1)
           {
               params.height = width + 4;
           }
           else
           {
               params.height = height + 4;
           }
            mParent.setLayoutParams(params);

            mImageView.invalidate();
            mParent.invalidate();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

        }
    });
```